# create custom layout product list woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to make a list of products woocommerce as warungssl..com shown are: the product name, normal price, discount prices, some attributes,  link or button that leads to a product detail page, and a link or button cart.

[image]

In Which file should I change the script code and I do not understand how to display multiple attributes.

Note:
 1. To (issuance, validation, and site seal) I will call the attribute
    data. The obstacles I did not understand the script.
 2. I make use of Wordpress themes porto
 3. The following examples are meant attributes

[image]

Maybe it could let me know where the location of the files that I have to change.

Please help me. Thank you